# Bootstrap 4 form validation then redirect the page to another ASPX page to complete the work

Tags: javascript

I am new to Bootstrap 4 and JavaScript.  I found a sample Bootstrap form validation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

It provides a nice validation but the script ends on after validation by pressing the "Submit Form" button.

Below is the script copy from the sample:

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

What I need is to forward the Submit with a POST request to another ASPX page to perform code behind work then save the form data into a database.  I think we could add some scripts to direct the application to call the ASPX page then display a modal pop up upon successful return from the ASPX page.  How can I add proper scripting to handle this?  Please advise.

Brandon.

Comment: uh, where is the redirect function in js..?
since it calls `event.preventDefault();` it will end up not invoking any other click events..

Comment: When a Send button is pressed on the form section (not show), it goes to the form.classList.add('was-validated') line.  I am hoping to add some js code here to call the ASPX page, wait for the ASPX response the pop up a modal screen to display success or failed message.  Just want to know how as I am new to javascript programming.  Thanks..

Comment: do you want to send the fields value using ajax to the aspx page? though, using aspx, you could do everything in _asp-way_, where you could validate the form inputs on postback or even using asp validator's client script..

Comment: Yes, fields will be sent to aspx page if I can call it.  I am taking advantage of the Bootstrap 4 client side validation features prior to send fields to the aspx page for posting data.  The question is based on the sample script above, how can I call the aspx page?

Comment: pardon me if i don't get your case correctly.. could you describe how the aspx will handle the page? will you submit the form as a query string? post request? or the form already on the aspx page where you used bootstrap 4 client side validation? if its the later case (bootstrap on the aspx page where the form is) you could force a postback. everything really depends on how you handled things on the backend..

Comment: I am moving a bit further that I can call the aspx via AJAX script listed below.  I place the call right under the line form.classlist('was-validated'); with call registerme();

Comment: However, it is calling the AJAX script regardless form validation failed or not.  How can I detect any form validation failed to avoid calling the AJAX script?

Comment: `if (form.checkValidity() === false)` checks whether the form is invalid, if it is so, disable further event (clicks, submission) with `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`. you could put an `else if` clause and call your `registerme();`

Comment: I added the form.checkValidity() == true then call registerme() below.  Now, it bypasses my  AJAX code without execution.  My AJAX code is resided in a separate custom.js file.

Comment: wait, could you update your post with the `form.checkValidity() == true` part?

Comment: Here is my partial code:form.classList.add('was-validated');
 if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
  $(document).submit(function () {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Registration.aspx',
    data: $("#reg_form").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
     $('.modal-body').html(result);
     $('#myModal').modal('show');},
    error: function (xhrReq, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);},
    statusCode:{
     403: function () {
      alert("403 Forbidden. You do not have permission for this action.");},
      ...

Comment: After further step thru the code, I notice the html is not waiting for AJAX to return and proceed to the step after the AJAX section.  I think AJAX is doing asynchronous call to the ASPX.  In fact, ASPX was executed and replied but the html has passed and carry on finishing execution prior to AJAX returned.  I guess I can't use AJAX call here.  Any suggestion?

Comment: * I think AJAX is doing asynchronous call to the ASPX.* umm, pardon me, i thought it already clear that _Asynchronous JavaScript And XML (AJAX)_ is already asynchronous. my suggestion are (1) to have somesort api end point (asp.net web api or your plain .svc or even a http handler) instead of processing it on the page directly or (2) [checks on the page whether the request is an AJAX request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest(v=vs.118).aspx) then returns a desired response or (3) invoke postback that is easier. you had three options.

Comment: Since AJAX is doing asynchronous call, I cannot use it here.  I need some sort of synchronous method to wait for the code behind page return.  Like you recommended, use postback option by adding action and method on the form to trigger the aspx code behind after validation.  How and where should I wait for the postback response from ASPX code behind?  Ideally, I would like to display a modal pop up after receiving text response from ASPX code behind.  Thanks.